# How to invoke child function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get alert from following function. It is working with a('10')() but not with a('10')

```
function a(m){
return function b(){
alert(m)
}
}

a('10');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function a(m) {
    return function b() {
        alert(m)
    }
}

a('10');

console.log(typeof a);
// function
console.log(typeof a('10'));
// function
```

It is because, when `a` is invoked, it returns another function from it. So, that function has to be explicitly invoked.

That is why we do `a('10')()`.

If this is too confusing for you, then just drop the inner function and invoke `alert` in the `a` function itself, like this

```
function a(m) {
    alert(m);
}
```

If alerting is the only task done inside the function, you are better off with executing the `alert` directly, like this

```
alert(m);
```

Comment: I like the answer with some description. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

rerun a self invoking function

```
function a(m){
  return (function b(){
      alert(m)
   })(m)
}
```

Now

```
 a('10') // 10
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need b function just alert in a.  Or if you do transfer the brackets to the end of the returning function

Comment: My question is to invoke child function